# SwiftUI - Respond to tap AND double tap with different actions

Tags: swiftui

I need to respond to a single tap and double tap with different actions, but is SwiftUI the double tap gesture is interpreted as two single taps.

In swift you can use fail gesture, but no idea how to do it in SwiftUI.

Example:

```
.onTapGesture(count: 1) {
     print("Single Tap!")
}
.onTapGesture(count: 2) {
     print("Double Tap!")
}
```

TIA.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First one prevent second one to perform. So reverse the order of your code:

```
.onTapGesture(count: 2) {
    print("Double Tap!")
}
.onTapGesture(count: 1) {
    print("Single Tap!")
}
```

#### Update: Second solution

Since the above method reported not working in some situationis, you can try using `gesture`s modifier instead:

```
.gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
    print("double clicked")
})
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
    print("single clicked")
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work right on macOS. It works, but the single tap callback is delayed by 200ms or so.

Comment: This also doesn't work if you do a triple tap over a double tap

Comment: As was mentioned, this approach causes a delay waiting for the second tap. The gestures must be simultaneous. See Asperi's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992089/swiftui-on-macos-handle-single-click-and-double-click-at-the-same-time

Comment: this is not working at all, this is the right answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72977593/1823922

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved with `exclusively(before:)`. It allows for only one gesture to succeed.

```
.gesture(
    TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
        print("DOUBLE TAP")
    }.exclusively(before: TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded {
        print("SINGLE TAP")
    })
)
```

Link to method documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gesture/exclusively(before:)

Comment: Adds delay in recognising single click

Answer (score 2):

```
Text("Tap Me!").gesture(      
TapGesture(count: 2)
    .onEnded({ print("Tapped Twice!")})
    .exclusively(before:
        TapGesture()
        .onEnded({print("Tapped Once!") })          
)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a simple solution (yet), most of these answers trigger both actions.
The workaround I have discovered feels clumsy, but works smoothly:

```
struct hwsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("HWS")
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Text single tapped")
                }
        }
        .highPriorityGesture(
            TapGesture(count: 2)
                .onEnded { _ in
                    print("hws double tapped")
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for double and triple taps to be recognised on an object but only trigger one of the action closures. I found that the `exclusively()` API didn't work for me on iOS 15. So, I created this little hack that does what I want.

```
Struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isTripleTap = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Button")
            .gesture(
                TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    Task {
                        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200_000_000)
                        
                        if !isTripleTap {
                            print("Double Tap")
                        }
                        
                        isTripleTap = false
                    }
                }
                .simultaneously(
                    with: TapGesture(count: 3).onEnded {
                        isTripleTap = true
                        print("Triple Tap")
                    }
                )
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems as well when having 2 or 3 clicks, sometimes the row reacted and sometimes not.
Solution, if there is nothing else to be clicked or handled in the row:

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

then the onTapGesture works every time!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can also setup a count for TapGesture like so:

```
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
    // double tap logic
})
```

Per Apple Developer Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tapgesture