# Handle single click and double click while updating the view

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a single and double click for grid view items on macOS. On the first click it should highlight the item. On the second click it should open a detail view.

```swift
struct MyGridView: View {

    var items: [String]
    @State var selectedItem: String?

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200, maximum: 270))
        ], alignment: .center, spacing: 8, pinnedViews: []) {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("Test")
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    print("double clicked")
                })
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                    self.selectedItem = item
                })
                .background(self.selectedItem == item ? Color.red : .blue)
            }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The highlighting works as expected without delay. But because the first click updates the view, the `TapGesture` for the double click is ignored. Only once the item was selected before, the double click also works, because it doesn't need to update the view again.

I was following https://stackoverflow.com/a/59992192/1752496 but it doesn't consider view updates after the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom click handler like this:

```swift
class TapState {

    static var taps: [String: Date] = [:]

    static func isDoubleTap<Content: View>(for view: Content) -> Bool {
        let key = "\(view)"
        let date = taps[key]
        taps[key] = Date()
        if let date = date, date.timeIntervalSince1970 >= Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - 0.4 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    public func onTapGesture(firstTap: @escaping () -> Void, secondTap: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        onTapGesture(count: 1) {
            if TapState.isDoubleTap(for: self) {
                secondTap()
            } else {
                firstTap()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And implement it like this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    @State var isSelected: Bool = false
    @State var isShowingDetail: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Text")
            .background(isSelected ? Color.green : Color.blue)
            .onTapGesture(firstTap: {
                isSelected = true
            }, secondTap: {
                isShowingDetail = true
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingDetail) {
                Text("Detail")
            }
    }
}
```

#### Swift Package

I've also created a small package you can use: https://github.com/lukaswuerzburger/DoubleTap

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes.... this should be _the_ answer when searching for this solution. Why hasn't apple made this easy to do already? From the base code, not the most elegant solution but it certainly works!

Comment: Hey @Chucky, thanks for your comment! I definitely agree about the code not being elegant. I haven't looked at this for a while. Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no build in function or something like that to understand deference between singleTap or doubleTap, but we have endless freedom to build what we want, I found this way:

You can apply **tapRecognizer** to anything you want, will work the same! for showing the use case I just applied to a Circle().

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .tapRecognizer(tapSensitivity: 0.2, singleTapAction: singleTapAction, doubleTapAction: doubleTapAction)
  
    }
    
    func singleTapAction() { print("singleTapAction") }
    func doubleTapAction() { print("doubleTapAction") }
  
}
```

---

```
struct TapRecognizerViewModifier: ViewModifier {

    @State private var singleTapIsTaped: Bool = Bool()

    var tapSensitivity: Double
    var singleTapAction: () -> Void
    var doubleTapAction: () -> Void

    init(tapSensitivity: Double, singleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void, doubleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.tapSensitivity = tapSensitivity
        self.singleTapAction = singleTapAction
        self.doubleTapAction = doubleTapAction
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        return content
            .gesture(simultaneouslyGesture)
 
    }

    private var singleTapGesture: some Gesture { TapGesture(count: 1).onEnded{
        
        singleTapIsTaped = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + tapSensitivity) { if singleTapIsTaped { singleTapAction() } }

    } }
    
    private var doubleTapGesture: some Gesture { TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded{ singleTapIsTaped = false; doubleTapAction() } }

    private var simultaneouslyGesture: some Gesture { singleTapGesture.simultaneously(with: doubleTapGesture) }

}


extension View {

    func tapRecognizer(tapSensitivity: Double, singleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void, doubleTapAction: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {

        return self.modifier(TapRecognizerViewModifier(tapSensitivity: tapSensitivity, singleTapAction: singleTapAction, doubleTapAction: doubleTapAction))
  
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesn't actually answer what I was asking. Recognizing single and double click already worked for me. The only problem if I want to update the view after the first click of a double click sequence, in order to highlight the "selected" state of an item, it doesn't recognize the second click of the double click anymore.

Comment: It seems that with your code, you will get both called when you double-tap on your View, I mean if you try double-tap, an unwanted single-tap would be happen for sure! In way I showed, I cover that issue, it means you will get just double-tap on your double-tap, and no more unwanted single-tap, also the code will remain responsive to single-tap as well!

Comment: Let me put it this way: one click highlights the view. a double click opens the detail. but the first click of the double click also highlights the view. But highlighting re-renders the view and, thus the double click handler is broken.

Comment: I already answered your issue in Answer and also in my last comment, it is no matter how you explain, I know what is happening, your app register an extra single click before double click get registered!

Comment: No man, i want that extra single click. I need it to highlight the view. The problem is that it doesn't register a double click if the view was not highlighted before. I better add some demo to show what's going on...

Comment: @swiftPunk This is exact answer that I'm looking for would you please change your code so we can use Custom logic with input for `singleTapAction` and ...    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783952/swiftui-ios-adding-double-tap-cause-single-tap-called-after-a-delay/68784775?noredirect=1#comment121565002_68784775 This is my question Link Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fdvfarzin: there is all ready designed to put your logic Code! See the code again. No need to improve.

Comment: @swiftPunk  I'm using it inside forEach and get a index for each item and want to pass a index in both singleTapAction and Double one ... singleTapAction(index : Int), I faced with the error `Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> Void'`

Comment: @fdvfarzin: Your issue isn’t related to the question topic or the answer topic! You should ask it as a question for that issue! It is can be answered by most of people.