# SwiftUI iOS - Adding Double tap cause Single tap called after a delay

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to recognize Single tap and Double tap on the `Capsule` below. This code works fine :

```
                         Capsule()
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 42)
                                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                                            print("Single Tap recognized instantly")
                                    }
```

But When I'm adding the `.onTapGesture(count: 2)` to it **Single tap called after 0.25ms.**

```
                         Capsule()
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 42)
                                    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                                            print("Double tap recognized instantly")
                                    }
                                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                                            print("Single Tap recognized after 0.25ms")
                                    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: look up simultaneous gesture

Comment: on simultaneous gesture before calling a Double tap guested once called Single tap and makes a bug on app

Comment: I tested your code and it works actually perfect, when I just double tap.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make one thing clear: You cannot have a single tap-gesture that should be recognized together with a double tap gesture when your goal is to detect both exclusively (i.e. the system should differentiate between a single tap and a double tap with no delay) since a single tap could theoretically always lead to a double tap. This means you always have to wait a certain period (of 0.25 ms as it seems in your case) to rule out the user intended to double-tap.

However, when your goal is to have a single tap-gesture together (in other words simultaneously) with the double-tap gesture, this is now completely feasible.

A gesture is, like so many things in SwiftUI a `protocol` and custom gestures can be built in a lot of ways like the `body` of a view. In your case, we want a double tap-gesture that runs simultaneously with a single tap gesture. The simplest way to this, you declare a computed property with an opaque return type (`some Gesture`) and describe your gesture in that property:

```swift
var tapGesture: some Gesture {
    TapGesture(count: 2)
        .onEnded {
            print("Double tap")
        }
        .simultaneously(with: TapGesture(count: 1)
                            .onEnded {
                                print("Single Tap")
                            })
}
```

You can simply add this gesture to whatever view you desire, just like you would do the same thing with any other gesture:

```swift
Capsule()
    .gesture(tapGesture)
```

Comment: Dear Schottky thanks for your perfect explanation your code removes the delay but makes a bug, every time I double tap on icon once Single tap Called and then Double tap called.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is not achievable then. As I tried to explain, the small delay is needed to detect whether a single tap could potentially be a double tap.

Comment: I think I found the right answer from @swiftPunk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66430942/handle-single-click-and-double-click-while-updating-the-view/66432412#66432412 unfortunately I don't know how to edit the code to get input for `singleTapAction` and ... so I can use custom logic.

Comment: But the solution there is exactly like the solution presented here… the first tap will be recognized, no matter if there is a second tap afterwards or not. Can you maybe elaborate a little bit more what it is exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: In your solution , App register an extra single click before double click get registered if you see the gif the swiftPunk put in his answer every time he Double tap on button there is no Single tap registration. this is what I want