# SwiftUI adding tap gesture with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayerviewcontroller

I have `AVPlayerViewController` wrapped in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and I call it `PlayerViewSUI`:

```
 public struct PlayerViewSUI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

       public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
           let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
           controller.player = player
           controller.showsPlaybackControls = showsPlaybackControls
           controller.delegate = context.coordinator
           return controller
       }
 }
```

The problem is if I add a tap gesture to `PlayerViewSUI`, it completely disables touches in `AVPlayerViewController`, including it's play button.

```
  PlayerViewSUI(player: player)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background {
                        Color.black
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 20)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar)
                    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    .onTapGesture(perform: {
                        print("Tapped")
                    })
```

I have tried simultaneous gesture as well to no avail. What is the solution out here?

Comment: What is a tap for on each board?

Comment: does this post (using overlay) answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77853165/how-to-expand-detectable-area-for-double-tap-in-swiftui

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine No, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean?